# creating get urls with parameters rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search form and on submission i'd like to send a get request with the parameter that was input into the text field

```
=form_for User.new, :url => 'search' do |f|
      = f.text_field :full_name, style: 'width: 84%;'
      = f.submit "Search", class: 'btn btn-primary', style: 'height: 40px;'
```

how would I construct the url for with the parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `=form_for User.new, :url => 'search',:method => :get`
Passing `:method => :get` explicitly.

Comment: how would i set the parameter from the value in the text_field?

Comment: If you want search value to be place on text field create instance variable in controller or simply use params[:full_name] for value

Comment: Use form_tag for searching watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form,                           http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form